# Flutter: How to print nested map to listView or futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, types

I have this response from my server and wants to print the values on screen, values keep returning null.

This is the json response:

```
{
  "responseCode": 99,
  "message": "User Found!",
  "responseData": {
    "id": 10,
    "role": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "CUSTOMER",
      "description": "This is the user of the application"
    },
    "firstName": "Austin",
    "lastName": "Miles",
    "createdOn": "2020-05-12T10:25:06.442+00:00",
    "dob": null,
    "emailAddress": "example@gmail.com",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "profilePhotoUrl": null,
    "profilePhotoFormat": null,
    "isDisabled": false
  }
}
```

This was the class I was using:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class User {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String password;
  String emailAddress;
  String phoneNumber;
  String profilePhoto;
  String role;
  String securityKey;
  String dob;
  String objectId;

  User(
      {this.firstName,
      this.lastName,
      this.password,
      this.emailAddress,
      this.dob,
      this.phoneNumber,
      this.profilePhoto,
      this.role,
      this.objectId,
      this.securityKey});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        firstName: json['firstName'] as String,
        lastName: json['lastName'] as String,
        password: json['password']as String,
        emailAddress: json['emailAddress']as String,
        phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber']as String,
        profilePhoto: json['profilePhoto']as String,
        role: json['role']as String,
        securityKey: json['securityKey']as String,
        dob: json['dob']as String,
        objectId: json['objectId']as String,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'firstName': firstName,
        'lastName': lastName,
        'password': password,
        'emailAddress': emailAddress,
        'dob': dob,
        'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
        'role': role,
        'profilePhoto': profilePhoto,
        'securityKey': securityKey,
      };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'User{firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, password: $password,emailAddress: $emailAddress, phoneNumber: $phoneNumber, profilePhoto: $profilePhoto,role: $role, securityKey: $securityKey, objectId: $objectId}';
  }
}

// List<User> userFromJson(String jsonData) {
//   final data = json.decode(jsonData);
//   return List<User>.from(data.map((item) => User.fromJson(item)));
// }

List<User> userFromJson(String str) =>
    List<User>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => User.fromJson(x)));

String userToJson(User data) {
  final jsonData = data.toJson();
  return json.encode(jsonData);
}


I made this attempt as follows on ProfilePage screen

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:ars_progress_dialog/ars_progress_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:project2/toks_model/user.dart';
import 'package:project2/utils/userHandler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  FlutterSecureStorage storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

  UserDialog usd;
  User userModel = User();

  getUser() async {
    String token = await storage.read(key: "token");
    progressDialog.show();

    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("http://BaseUrl/api/user/get-current-user-details"),
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
    );
    var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      userModel = User.fromJson({"responseData": jsonResponse});
      print(userModel);
      progressDialog.dismiss();
    });
  }

  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUser();
  }

  ArsProgressDialog progressDialog;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    progressDialog = ArsProgressDialog(context,
        blur: 2,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
        dismissable: false,
        loadingWidget: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          width: 220,
          height: 60,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
                child: Row(
              children: [
                CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                  radius: 20,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Text('Please wait...',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ],
            )),
          ),
        ));
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          // background image and bottom contents
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 200.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  //  color: Colors.blue,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('asset/pat4.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Sample APP' + '\n' + 'Serving your security needs',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Text(
                          userModel.firstName,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      thickness: 0.8,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.mail, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Text(
                          userModel.emailAddress,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.phone, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Text(
                          userModel.phoneNumber,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Text(
                      "Any thing else...",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          // Profile image
          Positioned(
            top: 150.0, // (background container size) - (circle height / 2)
            child: Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: userModel.profilePhoto != null
                      ? NetworkImage(userModel.profilePhoto)
                      : AssetImage("asset/imageicon.png"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: first, see if you get the data from the server correctly then see if it  your class is build correct or not

Comment: I'd be surprised if you even came as far as getting data from the server. Did you do any kind of debugging at all? Do you get any error messages in your log? Because you should...

Comment: It prints null on text, other times returns a type error

Comment: the error message is as follows:                                                       A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'

Answer (score 0):

As your API result, I think you should modify as below:

```dart
var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
setState(() {
   userModel = User.fromJson(jsonResponse["responseData"]);
   print(userModel);
   progressDialog.dismiss();
});
```

You should use `responseData` of API result.